# Cell Boundary Gtk Treeview Python

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk3, cellrenderer

I want to have a cell boundary like this:

[image: this]

But what Gtk Treeview gives me is this:

[image: this]

Is there any way I can achieve this in Gtk3 Python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the TreeView **[`set_grid_lines`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeView.html#Gtk.TreeView.set_grid_lines)** method set as both.

Example:

```
treeview.set_grid_lines(Gtk.TreeViewGridLines.BOTH)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , exactly what I wanted. Never thought it would be in doucmentation of Treeview , was messing around with Cell Renderer and Cell Renderer Text's documentation